# Check Magento Store Performance with APC or Memcache

Tags: magento-1.7, memcached

On my Server both APC and Memcached is installed. I have enabled both caching system one by one from local.xml each time.

In both cases I have checked site speed from Google Page Speed and Gtmetrix Speed test but its showing tha same grade as previous.

Here my question is: How can I check site performance after enabled APC OR Memcached. Or How can I check its working fine or not.

Please Help !!

Answer (score 3):

Pankaj,

*Contrary to popular belief*, neither using APC or Memcache as cache/session backends will make a noticeable difference to single-user page load time - **unless** you had a disk I/O bottleneck to begin with (meaning that the memory backed cache will outperform the slow disk based cache).

If you don't have I/O issues, then enabling them won't make a difference to the actual page load time.

Where they'll come into play is in high concurrency situations, synthetic benchmarks like Siege/AB will demonstrate this very clearly, with an almost 50% increase in request/s. How this translates to real-world performance however, isn't so dramatic.

You'll know if it is working if the `var/cache` directory is empty, and if using Memcache for sessions, if the `var/session` directory is empty.

If you use file-backed `slow_backend`, then you'll still see cache tag data created in `var/cache` - but not the cache data itself.

---

Bottom line, if you are trying to improve page-load time performance, changing the cache store isn't going to make a noticeable difference unless your server's HDDs are so contrained that serving files from disk *is* a bottleneck.